# Is it possible to use .elemgeo dot macro on the pyspatialite?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

I need to perform an `explode`, like `PostGIS ST_DUMP` on the QGIS plugin using pyspatialite.

There is a dot macro .elemgeo but I don't know if it is possible to call it from the pyqgis plugin via pyspatialite.

The version I use doesn´t have ElementaryGeometries table.

```
QGIS 2.8.1 Wien
Sqlite 3.7.17
SpatiaLite 4.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS `St_Dump` is used to split a GeometryCollection into multiples records (rows).

You can use  the new [SpatiaLite:VirtualElementary](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualElementary)

1) open a SpatiaLite database

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as db
conn = db.connect('multipoly.db3')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT AsText(Geometry) from mulipol"
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in cur.execute(sql):
    print i 
(u'MULTIPOLYGON(((-0.527529 0.556978, -0.117798 0.290653, -0.256082 0.019206, -0.709347 -0.088348, -0.862996 0.183099, -0.734955 0.398207, -0.527529 0.556978)), ((0.199744 0.060179, 0.548015 0.129321, 0.729834 0.039693, 0.814341 -0.139565, 0.701665 -0.385403, 0.476312 -0.50064, 0.268886 -0.423816, 0.189501 -0.229193, 0.199744 0.060179)), ((-0.37644 -0.295775, -0.115237 -0.359795, -0.033291 -0.580026, -0.115237 -0.741357, -0.307298 -0.859155, -0.588988 -0.692702, -0.65557 -0.475032, -0.37644 -0.295775)))',)
```

2) Then you can use the

> final example shows how you can construct a SQL query dynamically resolving all complex geometries form a whole table into individual elementary items

```
sql = "SELECT t.id, e.item_no, ST_AsText(e.geometry) FROM multipol AS t JOIN ElementaryGeometries AS e ON (e.f_table_name = 'multipol' AND e.origin_rowid = t.id);"
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in cur.execute(sql):
   print i 
(1, 0, u'POLYGON((-0.527529 0.556978, -0.117798 0.290653, -0.256082 0.019206, -0.709347 -0.088348, -0.862996 0.183099, -0.734955 0.398207, -0.527529 0.556978))')
(1, 1, u'POLYGON((0.199744 0.060179, 0.548015 0.129321, 0.729834 0.039693, 0.814341 -0.139565, 0.701665 -0.385403, 0.476312 -0.50064, 0.268886 -0.423816, 0.189501 -0.229193, 0.199744 0.060179))')
(1, 2, u'POLYGON((-0.37644 -0.295775, -0.115237 -0.359795, -0.033291 -0.580026, -0.115237 -0.741357, -0.307298 -0.859155, -0.588988 -0.692702, -0.65557 -0.475032, -0.37644 -0.295775))')
```

Comment: Hi @gene, thanks for your attention, but the problem is that the version I use for old projects does not have the ElementaryGeometries table. In the new projects I have already implemented this way. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ElementaryGeometries function:

```
SELECT ElementaryGeometries (<source-table>, <geom>, <target-table>, 'pk', 'old-pk');
```

It is documented like this:

```
ElementaryGeometries( in_table Text , geom_column Text , out_table Text , out_pk Text , out_multi_id Text ) : Integer
```

> Will create a new out_table directly corresponding to in_table. The
>   output table will be arranged in such a way that each row will always
>   contain an elementary Geometry; so each time that a MULTI-type
>   Geometry is found in the input table it will be split into mamy
>   distinct rows. out_pk is the name to be set for the output Primary
>   Key, and out_multi_id is the name to be set for a second column within
>   the output table where to store the original Primary Key. The optional
>   argument transaction determines if an internal SQL Transaction should
>   be automatically started or not (the default setting if not explicitly
>   overridden is TRUE).

- SpatiaLite version ..: 4.3.0a
- SQLite version ......: 3.22.0

Comment: ElementaryGeometries fails if <target-table> already exists so precede with `select DropGeoTable(<target-table>)`